# How to restore Hyper-V VMs from a crashed Windows 2008 R2 server?

Tags: restore, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

We had a windows 2008 R2 server with a lot of VMs in it which crashed. We were able to recover the content of the "Hyper-V" folder located in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V from the crashed server. The VHDs are stored in a RAID 5 drive which are safe. 
We have now replaced the hard-drive and reinstalled Windows 2008 R2. How can I restore all VMs and their snapshots using the recovered "Hyper-v" folder?
I have tried below with no luck:
- I stopped the Hyper-v service
- Replaced "Hyper-v" with recovered one
- Restarted the server and it can't load the VMs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the powershell cmdlet [Import-VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/import-vm?view=win10-ps)

```
 Import-VM -Path 'C:\<vm export path>\2B91FEB3-F1E0-4FFF-B8BE-29CED892A95A.vmcx'
```

You can copy the VM if you don't want to register in-place:

```
Import-VM -Path 'C:\<vm export path>\2B91FEB3-F1E0-4FFF-B8BE-29CED892A95A.vmcx' -Copy
```